# How to implementation linear search in String Class Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to search for specific characters in a string list. For example, `string_list = ['sasasd']`; I want to search for `'sa'`. The linear function will return True, but I tried many times, It can not return True.

```
class String:
    def __init__(self, str_value = []):
        self.value = str_value

    def search_data(self,target_value):
        m = len(self.value)

        for i in range(m):
            if self.value[i] == target_value:
                return True
        return False


     value_data = ['dasdasd']
     my_str = String(value_data)
     result = my_str.search_data('da')
     print(result)
```

Comment: You should also look into why using mutable arguments as default values is a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your code.

`str_value` is a list and you initialize the value of the class attribute like this: `self.value = str_value`. So, when you give it the value `['dasdasd']`, you end up having a list with one string element.

When declaring the m variable, `m = len(self.value)`, you compute the number of elements from that list **NOT** the number of characters from the string value inside the list (`m = len(['dasdasd']) = 1`).

Also, the for that searches for the `target_value` string inside the `self.value` string is incorrect.

Quick fix to correct the current code:

```
class String:

    def __init__(self, str_value = []):
        self.value = str_value

    def search_data(self, target_value):
        # assumption here that self.value has the format: ['string'] (list with 1 string element)
        if self.value[0].find(target_value) == 0:
            return True

        return False


 value_data = ['dasdasd']
 my_str = String(value_data)

 result = my_str.search_data('da')
 print(result)
```

Tested and it outputs True.

Comment: I only use len() because my teacher does not allow for me to use built in function. He only allows to use len().

Comment: Ok, but what I meant is that you use `len()` incorrectly. You should call it like `len(self.value[0])` if you want to get the number of characters from the string inside the list.